# Kernel Panic in Debian after converting disk from Hyper-V to VirtualBox

Tags: hyper-v, virtualbox

I have a problem after moving the VM from HyperV to VirtualBox running Debian 10. After booting, I have ShellUEFI and then I run grub64 and then the panic kernel appears.
Interestingly, I don't have this problem with Ubuntu ... only Debian is problematic.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Virtualbox and Hyper-v normally use different disk controllers.
Try this:
Open Virtualbox
Create new VM
Use above VHD as hard drive.
Once VM is created, go to VM settings, storage,
Add new controller PIIX4.
Move VHD from SATA controller to PIIX4 controller.
Press OK, load VM.

Beware though, if you keep hyper-v and virtualbox installed on the same machine, the virtualbox vm will be extremely slow. You need to either completely disable or uninstall hyper-V to make it work properly.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).